# Blazor reusable form field component using EF

Tags: generics, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have another n00b question, that hopefully has a simple solution.

Let's say I have a database, with several tables, with several columns, like all data applications.
Many of the columns will be edited in several locations, but maybe not the whole table in each location (e.g a Customer can change it's name, but it's credit limit can only be changed in the admin control panel).
Creating forms tied specifically to each table and column, using the data classes is no problem to do, but it's not easily managed if I want to change the design of the form and add functions to the inputs.

So what I want to do is to make a generic component for rendering a form row containing one single property. Then use the component to add the required fields for each form.

Let's say in the admin/customers/{CustomerId:int} page I want to do the following

```
<h2>Edit customer</h2>
<FormField Entity="currentCustomer" Property="@(() => nameof(currentCustomer.Name))" />
<FormField Entity="currentCustomer" Property="@(() => nameof(currentCustomer.CreditLimit))" />
```

Or something similar.

The will have an editContext, handle validation and database modification, but the employee details page will load the entity and pass it to the component.

I have found that I can use `@typeparam TEntity` in the component, to pass a generic type, but I'm not able to find out how I can actually use it to retreive and update it.

In my component, tied to one property only, I have this code, so you may better understand my intentions. I want this to be possible to use for all database columns.

```
@if (editContext == null)
{
    <Loading />
}
else
{
    <EditForm EditContext="editContext">
        <FormRow>
            <LeftColumn>
                <FormFieldLabel For="@(() => editModel.Field)" />
            </LeftColumn>
            <MiddleColumn>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="editModel.Field" class="form-control" />
                    @if (updating)
                    {
                        <div class="input-group-text text-primary border-primary">
                            <div class="lds-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    @if (error)
                    {
                        <div class="input-group-text text-danger border-danger"><Svg Name="exclamationmark" /></div>
                    }
                    @if (success)
                    {
                        <div class="input-group-text text-success border-success"><Svg Name="checkmark" /></div>
                    }
                    <span class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick="Reset"><Svg Name="arrowundo" /></span>
                </div>
            </MiddleColumn>
            <RightColumn>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => editModel.Field)" class="text-danger" />

            </RightColumn>
        </FormRow>
        @if (exception != null)
        {
            <FormRow>
                <MiddleColumn>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Retry</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" @onclick="Reset">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" @onclick="@(() => showException = true)">Show Exception</button>
                    @if (showException)
                    {
                        <p><br />@exception.Message</p>
                    }
                </MiddleColumn>
            </FormRow>
        }
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    </EditForm>
}



@code {
    [Parameter] public required Employee Entity { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public required ApplicationDbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    private EditContext? editContext;
    private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;
    private EditModel editModel = new();

    private int updateResult = 0;
    private bool updating = false;
    private bool error = false;
    private bool success = false;
    private bool showException = false;
    private Exception? exception;

    private string? initialValue;


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editModel.Field = Entity.BankAccount;
        initialValue = Entity.BankAccount;

        editContext = new(editModel);
        editContext.OnFieldChanged += HandleFieldChanged;

        messageStore = new(editContext);
    }

    async void HandleFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        updating = false;
        error = false;
        success = false;
        messageStore!.Clear(() => editModel.Field!);
        showException = false;
        exception = null;
        if (editContext!.Validate())
        {
            updating = true;
            Entity.BankAccount = editModel.Field;
            try
            {
                DbContext.Entry(Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                updateResult = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                updating = false;
                error = true;
                messageStore!.Add(() => editModel.Field!, "Error occured while saving.");
                exception = ex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error = true;
        }

        if (updateResult > 0)
        {
            updating = false;
            success = true;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        updating = false;
        error = false;
        success = true;
        editModel.Field = initialValue;
        messageStore!.Clear(() => editModel.Field!);
        showException = false;
        exception = null;
        editContext!.NotifyFieldChanged(editContext.Field(nameof(editModel.Field)));
    }

    private class EditModel
    {
        [MaxLength(20), Display(Name = "Bank account")] public string? Field { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I load the component like this:

```
            @if (employee == null)
            {
                <Loading />
            }
            else
            {
                <BankAccount Entity="employee" DbContext="context" />
            }

@code {
    [Parameter] public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    private ApplicationDbContext? context { get; set; }
    private Employee? employee;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
            employee = await context.Employees.FindAsync(EmployeeId);
            if (employee == null)
            {
               //
            }

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Or maybe I shuldn't do it this way at all..?
Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: `shouldn't do it this way at all`. The idea of a component that goes all the way from the UI to the database was tried and **abandoned** in the early 2000s, because it's hardly possible to use the same *GUI element* for every use case, much less the same model in the UI, the business classes *and* the database. What makes for a good UI doesn't make for a good business entity or database table (or tables).

Comment: WPF, Silverlight and *all* SPA frameworks use an MVVM-derived model instead, where GUIs built to server the end user's scenarios use data-binding to pull data from services, caches, databases, local or remote, without ever bothering with the actual storage implementation

Comment: For example, how would a vertical component like this handle *caching* of lookup data, like  business units, employee levels or other stuff that doesn't change? That data may come from Redis directly, a singleton dictionary, or the caching middleware. Would you add that to every UI component?

Comment: BTW this component is tightly coupled with the *configuration* of the database. Either the component itself or the DbContext will have to explicitly read the database connection string or configuration. This is avoided in all the tutorials and docs by using dependency injection and a DbContextFactory (at the very least) to create DbContext instances *only* when needed, based on settings provided through an `AddDbContext` call during startup. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection and *shouldn't* be kept around for long

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.  You should collect your comments together as an answer.  You ARE answering the question: "Or maybe I shuldn't do it this way at all..?"   Which is what my answer does in a different way.  I'll give you an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gone through your code line by line, but what I think I see is you trying to create a variant of what I call the *Quest for the Generic Edit Form*: search *Quest for the Holy Grail* if you don't understand my analogy. [Forgive me if I'm wrong].

> Or maybe I shuldn't do it this way at all..?

Your decision, but there's a lot of complexity to such an approach and, as you expand the functionality to include different types of edit controls, the complexity starts to get horrendous.  How do you handle a select, a radio button control?

Think *Single Resposibility Principle* and *Separation of Concerns*.

I take a different approach.  It may provide a different perspective on what you seek to achieve.

My data pipeline is `record` based and thus immutable.  Editing is through a `RecordEditContext' class, built from the the original record, and exposing properties for fields that can be edited.  Save creates a new copy of the record, and submits it into the data pipeline to persist.

Use different record edit contexts [and different Fluent Validation validators] for different scenarios.

I turn the generic form concept around.

I boilerplate the edit code into an abstract wrapper component that contains all the `EditContext` stuff, the buttons and the form logic.

I have composite edit controls (with the Bootstrap row/column control, label and validation display all built in).

My record *Editor* code just defines the fields and basic row layout like this:

```cs
@inherits EditorFormBase<Product, ProductEditContext, ProductEntityService, ProductValidator>

<div class="row">

    <BlazrTextControl class="form-control mb-2"
                      ColumnCss="col-12 mb-2"
                      Label="Product Name"
                      UpdateOnInput
                      @bind-Value=this.Presenter.RecordContext.ProductName />

    <BlazrTextControl class="form-control mb-2"
                      ColumnCss="col-12 col-lg-6 mb-2"
                      Label="Product Code"
                      UpdateOnInput
                      @bind-Value=this.Presenter.RecordContext.ProductCode />

    <BlazrNumberControl class="form-control mb-2"
                        ColumnCss="col-12 col-lg-6 mb-2"
                        Label="Unit Price £"
                        UpdateOnInput
                        @bind-Value=this.Presenter.RecordContext.ProductUnitPrice />

</div>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

My demo project is a toy plane shop!

Comment: Ok, so basically, I can't, or shouldn't do it this way.
Quest for the Generic Edit Form is probably exactly what this is :D

I understand your concern about different edit controls, my plan was to add more parameters where different controls were needed, or make 2-3 different components (3 components would be a lot easier to maintain than one per database caloumn).

Anyways, I will continue my quest to create better, reusable, components. However, if you have some more good tips to point me in the right direction, I would be grateful :)

Comment: Problem with looking at other apps, guides, etc, is they are way too simple, or way too advanced, and it ends up with no use.
My last app was MVC v 2 using Visual Basic (coming from classic ASP/VB.Net), that was 7 year ago. So .net core and C# is almost like learning to walk again...

Comment: NP.  I was a Sharepoint Consultant for many years - classic ASP/VB.Net.  Retired and went travelling.  Covid and a project for a business I know pushed me back to coding and the nascent Blazor.  I'm back hooked again for fun and the knowledge.  The Repo for the above code is here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.  I'm in the middle of documenting it.  It may not be too "too complicated".

Comment: I will definitely have a look at your Toy plane shop, and see if I can catch some good ideas :)
Thank you!