# Blazor remotevalidation for dynamic field?

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to achieve a remote validation on fields that are dynamically generated but couldn't find any solution. I tried Custom Validation by passing `EditContext` as `CascadingParameter` but with my limited knowledge I couldn't make it through.

Example case,
Imagine you're generating a list of input from List emails, and for each of the email user enters, the Blazor will do a remote validation on the backend via API to check whether the entered email exists or not, and accordingly, it'll show ValidationMessage below the field and mark the `EditForm` Invalid(not submittable)

Comment: When you step into dynamically generated forms, you need to build your own dynamic validators and dynamic Edit State trackers.  The standard stuff isn't designed for that context.

Comment: [Polite] See this recent answer - and other peoples comments - on what I term the "Quest for the Generic Edit Form" which I think is where this question is coming from -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649530/13065781.  I may of course be totally wrong!